# How to get a basic Flexbox Layout (Like That of a 2x TD Table)?

Tags: css, flexbox

(**NOTE:** There's a bit of backstory here about how I *used to* get this effect; feel free to skip to the bold text at the end if you don't care.)

Back in the dark old days, if you wanted to have an image with a variable width, and some text next to it, you would just do it with a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- This TD will magically grow to fit its image -->
    <td><img src="someImage.png"/></td>

    <!-- This TD will magically grow to fill the remaining space -->
    <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, in modern web design we should be using CSS not tables, and I know how to get a similar effect by using `float: left` on both the image and the text.

But, `float` is passe now too, and everyone uses (wrapping) flexboxes for layouts.  However, when I do:

```
<div style="display: flexbox; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div><img src="someImage.png"/></div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum ...</div>
</div>
```

My text div appears below my image div.  I can fix this by putting explicit `max-width` styles on both, but then my text `<div>` no longer fills the space left by the image (eg. if I have a smaller image, I wind up with a bunch of whitespace).

My question is: **how can I create a flexbox of an image side-by-side with some text ... but have the two "columns" of the flexbox adjust themselves so that the image column is as wide as the image, and the text column is as wide as "whatever space is left"**?

Comment: Maybe a bit too much, so I won't put it in an answer, but my last codepen is a nice example of how to use a simple *flexbox* mechanism to create sophisticated tables. Check the CSS *mechanism* section for the basics and CSS section *eye-candy* for some extra trickery. Just fork and ab()use it: [Codepen: Flexbox N-grid](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/gOvWZwq?editors=0100). In the remainder of the demo I added a link back to this SO and some demo pictures. All responsive sizing is controlled with math *linear equation y=mx+b* without `@media` queries. Comment there for more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this you just need to use `flex-wrap:nowrap` it will force the flex items into a single line giving full width to the image and rest to the text.
Below are two codes

#### 1. with nowrap

```html
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;">
    <div><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg"></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;">
    <div><img src="https://www.imaging-resource.com/?ACT=44&fid=17&d=5221&f=zimg_1447.jpg"></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;">
    <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/88/Vegeta_Dragon_Ball.jpg/220px-Vegeta_Dragon_Ball.jpg"></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

#### 2.with wrap

```html
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg"></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div><img src="https://www.imaging-resource.com/?ACT=44&fid=17&d=5221&f=zimg_1447.jpg"></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/88/Vegeta_Dragon_Ball.jpg/220px-Vegeta_Dragon_Ball.jpg"></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but without wrap, it won't wrap around on small screens.  I want the flexbox effect on a small screens, but just on large screens I want the image to the left and the text to the right.

Comment: @machineghost for that you could use media queries

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your text column to wrap around into a new row if there's not enough space for it alongside a large image, you can simply remove the `flex-wrap` from your container.

Is this the kind of behaviour you're looking for?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#largeImage {
  width: 400px;
}

#smallImage {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="largeImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg/1200px-Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="smallImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg/1200px-Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Reading through the [MDN basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and perhaps also [CSS-tricks' 'A complete guide to Flexbox'](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will help get you up to speed.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have this repeated with multiple different images, and I need the image size to vary based on the actual image sizes, so I can't hardcode the widths :(  With a table it doesn't matter what the image's size is, it just increases the column width to match.